# Subdivide loop at custom position without stretching the texture

Tags: texturing, modeling

How can one subdivide at an arbitrary position, say the cylinder side faces, using CTRL+R (subdivide loop tool), so that the texture is not stretched like this:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

If this is not possible with this tool, is there another way, like for instance recalculating a group of UV coordinates by means of their vertex position and their surrounding vertices.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The loop cut operator has an option to correct UVs. Enable it in the *redo panel*, below the tool shelf or with <kbd>F6</kbd>:

[image]

You could also use the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>), with angle constrain (<kbd>C</kbd>) and cut through (<kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Wow man! that was fast!, and that GIF video screen capture is awesome.

Comment: It's called LICEcap if you want to try it out.

Comment: It's only partially related but I want to note for the record that "Inset Faces" also works without distorting the texture mapping - great if you're adding more detail to an already-textured mesh.